# Count the number of items in an array using Twig while in an IF statement

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm building an help centre for an application and I want to be able to display the number of topics within a specific category. At the moment, this is what I have:

```
{% for cat in cats %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#helpcategories" href="#category{{cat.id}}">
                    {{cat.category}}
                    {% for top in tops %}
                        {% if top.category == cat.id %}
                            <span class="badge pull-right">
                                {{ tops|length }}
                            </span>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="category{{cat.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    {% for top in tops %}
                        {% if top.category == cat.id %}
                            <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{top.title}}</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, I use Twig to sort out the topics in to their respective categories. As you can also see, in the area that I want to display the number of topics within a category I am using `{{tops|length}}`. However, this returns the number of topics in total, not per category.

How can I get Twig to count the number of times a topic appears in a category?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not using your templating language to build those counts but to do it in your application before you get to the template because that would enable you to display total counts before pagination if you ever decide to paginate.